# How to replace columns of a matrix with an unsorted ordered list.

Tags: matrix, replacement, sorting, column

I have a matrix that I would like to replace the values of each column with where they are in an ordered list of values from least to greatest.  For example, if I have

```
m={{.5,17},{.2,42},{.7,2}}
```

I would like to transform it to

```
m2={{2,2},{1,3},{3,1}}.
```

I understand how SortBy and Replace work, but I'm not sure how to use them together to in this case, since I do not actually want to values sorted in the end.

Answer (score 6):

```
Transpose[Ordering@Ordering@# & /@ Transpose@m]
```

> {{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}}

**Edit**

[jjc385](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11035/jjc385) suggests this neat modification:

```
Transpose[Ordering@*Ordering /@ Transpose@m]
```

> {{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}}

Comment: You beat me by a minute!  I personally find it cleaner to use `Composition` (`@*`)  rather than a pure function in cases like this.  +1

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with a single column:  `col = {0.5, 0.2, 0.7}`.  Applying [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) to it gives

```
Ordering @ col
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 3}
> ```

This tells us the smallest element is at position 2 in the original list, the next smallest is at position 1, and the largest is at position 3.  This isn't quite what we want, but we can get that by applying [`InversePermutation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InversePermutation.html) :

```
InversePermutation @ Ordering @ col
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 3}
> ```

(The last example in 'Properties & Relations' in the docs for `InversePermutation` might be helpful.)

To do this for the columns of the matrix, you can transpose, apply this procedure, and transpose the result:

```
Transpose @* Map[ InversePermutation @* Ordering ] @* Transpose @ m
```

> ```
> {{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}}
> ```

```
SameQ[%, m2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked great!